# How can an MFC application terminate itself?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

What is the proper way for an MFC application to cleanly close itself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Programatically Terminate an MFC Application

```
 void ExitMFCApp()
   {
        // same as double-clicking on main window close box
        ASSERT(AfxGetMainWnd() != NULL);
        AfxGetMainWnd()->SendMessage(WM_CLOSE);
   }
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117320

Answer (score 14):

```
AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 4):

In support of @Mike's answer, the reason to use this method is to trigger the correct shutdown sequence. Especially important for MDI/SDI applications because it gives a chance for documents to prompt for save before exit or to cancel the exit.

@Matt Noguchi, your method will circumvent this sequence (which may be the desired effect, I suppose, but you've probably got *problems* if you're short-circuiting the normal teardown.

Answer (score 4):

```
PostQuitMessage( [exit code] );
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a dialog based application you can do it by calling EndDialog() function.

If it is an SDI/MDI based application you can call DestroyWindow. But before which you will need to do the cleanup yourself (closing documents, deallocating memory and resources, destroying any additional windows created etc).